# How to pass --add-exports to Strimzi Kafka Connect?

Tags: java, apache-kafka-connect, strimzi

I'm using Strimzi 0.33.0 (which uses Java 17) and one of my connect plugins still needs to access `sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper`. Obviously JVM throws:

```
cannot access class sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper (in module java.management) because module java.management does not export sun.management to unnamed module @0x478cc5f1
```

So I need to pass `--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED` to JVM. Looking at the documentation, `jvmOptions` section doesn't support such a feature. Is there any other approach to enable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code [kafka_connect_run.sh](https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/blob/main/docker-images/kafka-based/kafka/scripts/kafka_connect_run.sh), injecting `STRIMZI_JAVA_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES` environment variable, resolves the issue.

```
connectContainer:
  env:
    - name: STRIMZI_JAVA_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES
      value: "--add-exports=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED"
```